# How to Stop SPARK from setting new Hive VERSION

Tags: apache-spark, hive

my HIVE Metastore verison is 2.1.0. But when I launch my Spark-shell it updates the Version to 1.2.0.

```
17/06/11 12:04:03 WARN DataNucleus.General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/root/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/root/spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
17/06/11 12:04:07 ERROR metastore.ObjectStore: Version information found in metastore differs 2.1.0 from expected schema version 1.2.0. Schema verififcation is disabled hive.metastore.schema.verification so setting version.
17/06/11 12:04:09 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
```

This causes my HIVE to stop working. 
I have tried to set **spark.sql.hive.metastore.version 2.1.0** in **spark-defaults.conf**....then my spark-shell is not working.
Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to disable version verification by updating your hive-site.xml

```
 <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
    <!-- <value>true</value> -->
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
      Enforce metastore schema version consistency.
      True: Verify that version information stored in is compatible with one from Hive jars.  Also disable automatic
            schema migration attempt. Users are required to manually migrate schema after Hive upgrade which ensures
            proper metastore schema migration. (Default)
      False: Warn if the version information stored in metastore doesn't match with one from in Hive jars.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer... However, I found a solution for this issue, it was solved with a new patch for Spark.